# Exporting .vcf contact with their group informations

Tags: contacts, mobile-phones, vcf-vcard

Is there a way to export a .vcf (or .csv ) file containing all contacts file not only contact name but also the field of group that contact belong ?

the normal .vcf exporting to sdcard is not concluant because there is no group fields.

It is for the phone contact (not specially google contacts).

The method is to use an easy phone method (e.g: using android export vcf to sdcard instead of coding it in Java) or use an existing python script that can fetch contact informations and group fields.

The goal is then upload the result .vcf file into another Android device to restore the group of contacts